# How to average out values of Textview inside a listView

Tags: android, android-listview, average

I 'm devoloping an app with a listview , every row is populated with various objects including a Textview  with int value,  how can I average out the valus contained in the textview in my listview ? thanks

Comment: what do you mean by "how can I average out the value of every textview"?

Comment: for example I have two rows, in the first one I have value 4, in the second I have value 2, how can I obtain the average 3? ps. I edit the title, thanks

Comment: you have to check the data source via which you are adding values to textviews? Avg out from that data source.

Comment: thanks , but I don't understand completely,  you mean I have to average out the Database data?

Comment: Exactly, If you are not changing the data on run time, you can take values and avg them out.

Comment: unfortunately I'm changing data on run time, thanks for answer anyway

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should implement a method of counting the average values in your adapter

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter{

        ......

        public int getAverageValue(){
            int result = 0;
            if(getCount() > 0) {
                for (int i = 0; i < getCount(); i++) {
                    AdapterDataItem item = getItem(i);
                    result += item.getYourInt();
                }
                result = result/getCount();
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
```

this is not the end result you will need to adjust for themselves

Comment: Thank you,  I use your code with little adjustments,  it works

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the calculation of that average will be performed on some view click which is not a part of `ListView`.

In `ListView`'s `Adapter` you must be passing the `ArrayList` of some Java Model class. That class will have one variable which will represent the value entered by user. You have to store the value on focus change listener.

After user click the Calculate Average button. You simply iterate through the `ArrayList` and apply the formula of average i.e. `Sum of All Values/ Number` of Values